# How to access ethereum/client-go shell outside docker container

Tags: go-ethereum

I have just started learning Blockchain and following a [YouTube tutorial](http://youtube.com/watch?v=QCvL-DWcojc&t=2827s) . In that tutorial he installed ethereum by cloning the repo , but I have installed the ethereum/go-client using docker as per the instructions given in [official documentation](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/install-and-build/installing-geth#run-inside-docker-container) . I am beginner to Docker too . When I run the docker container using `docker run -it -p 30303:30303 ethereum/client-go` command , my terminal looks like this :-
[image]

Now I want to make an account using `personal.newAccount()` command . But where I should run this command ? Container is not providing me any shell where I can run this command .

I have searched about this lot on internet but doesn't get a solution , all of them is showing how to install geth using docker only .

Please help me . I have just started learning blockchain .

Thank

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange.

The following should enable you to connect to the Geth console through the Docker container. There may be other ways of accomplishing the same thing.

1. Find the name of the container running Geth

The following command will list all running Docker containers:

```
docker ps
```

make note of the name and/or id

2. Connect to the container

```
docker exec -it <NAME OR ID> bash
```

This should put the terminal "in" the Docker container.

*(Note: if this command gives you a `no such file or directory: unknown.` error, try replacing `bash` with `sh`, `zsh`, or `ash`. It depends on which shell is installed in the container by default. ([Source](https://garrymarsland.com/how-to-connect-to-a-running-docker-container/))*

3. Create an account

Your reference to `personal.newAccount()` seems to be a reference to the Geth console. You'll need to find the `.ipc` file Geth creates while running and connect to it. You may already know where it is. If you don't, you should be able to use:

```
find / -name "geth.ipc"
```

make note of the path

4. Open the Geth Console

```
geth attach path/to/geth.ipc
```

This should open the Geth JavaScript console in the terminal. You will now be able to use `personal.newAccount()`!

(Please note that this answer assumes that you want to use the Geth console, and not `clef`.)

**Note:** While researching the answer to this question, I came across something that might be useful for you. Running these commands as is will **not** save the data between sessions. That means that if you are syncing a public network (testnet or mainnet), that you'll need to restart syncing from the beginning every time you launch the container.  If you'd like to save the sync data to disk, then when you run `docker run`, you should add the `-v` flag along with the path you want the data saved in, like this:

```bash
docker run -it -p 30303:30303 -v /path/on/host:/root/.ethereum ethereum/client-go
```

where `/path/on/host` is the directory the data should be saved in. ([Source](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-run-geth-from-a-docker-container-b6d30620ca74/))

Comment: 2nd step is showing _"OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/bash": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory: unknown"_  error

Comment: I added a few alternatives, trying the same command with either `sh` or `ash` at the end should work (not sure which - it depends what shell is installed in your container). Let me know if it works!

Comment: I think installed shell is sh in container . But when I ran _"geth attach home/rishabh/Desktop/geth.ipc"_ it shows me this error -"Unable to attach to remote geth: dial unix home/rishabh/Desktop/geth.ipc: connect: no such file or directory"_ whereas geth.ipc file is present on my desktop I can see it.

Comment: that path (`/home/rishabh`) sounds like it's not in the Docker container - could it be that you are also running Geth in your regular env (not Docker), and that you searched for the `ipc` there (as opposed to in the terminal that is "inside" the Docker container)? Also, it looks like you may be missing a `/` at the beginning of the path (`/home/` instead of `home/`)

Comment: I am running "geth attach home/rishabh/Desktop/geth.ipc" docker container

Answer (score 0):

docker exec -it  /bin/sh

should do it at least with new images as of 2/23/22